# having trouble hiding gridview column in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView1 with 5 columns and the first column is the Delete row.  when a user clicks on submit, i want to call this function to hide that column while the vb.net codebehind runs until its done.

i can get to alert(here-2) but i don't get to here-3?? not sure why??

```
      function hideColumn() {
        alert("here-1");
        col_num = 0;    // document.getElementById("column_numbder").value;
        alert("here-2");
        rows = document.getElementById("divMain.GridView1").rows;
        alert("here-3");
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].cells[col_num].style.display = "none";
         }
        alert("here-4");
    }
```

here is my gridview information:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="both" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting"  >
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" DeleteText="Remove"  />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#99ccff" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: jQuery could make your life easier: `$("#gridId tr td:nth-child("+col_num+")").hide()`

Comment: Is 'divMain.GridView1' the element Id? If you are representing id with the classname, then its wrong. getElementId wont work.

Comment: Sivakumar: i tried it with just GridView1 and that didn't work either.

Comment: mshsayem 6:  do i just put that piece of code under alert(here-1)?

Comment: i added my gridview info, can someone help me?

Comment: OR, is there a way to disable the Remove button, so that it can't be clicked while a user waits5-10 seconds while the process runs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the elements.

```
window.onload = function () {

    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');

    var buttons = grid.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].innerText === "Remove") {
            var button = buttons[i];
            button.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
        }
    }

    function handleClick(evt) {
        this.style.display = "none";
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

The `evt.preventDefault()` was for me to be able to test it, you might not need it.

Comment: thanks for attempt but it didn't work.  it 'may' have worked after codebehind ran but i want it to happen BEFORE codebehind runs.  i tried putting yr code in its own function and then on my input button onclick i called it and it still didn't work.

Comment: @PurdyRA this should not be inside any function. Put it by itself, I have tested this and it works.

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Comment: i put some alerts and i see it firing off, just doesn't remove the REMOVE column.

Comment: i don't see it getting to this line:   if (buttons[i].innerText === "Remove") {